# DialogFragment with DatePickerDialog don't change content after screen rotation and leak memory at onCreateDialog()

Tags: android

I create a DatePickerDialog with DialogFragment as following:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
public static final String TAG = DatePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public interface OnDateUpdateListener{
    public void onDateUpdate(int year, int month, int day);
}

private OnDateUpdateListener mOnDateUpdateListener;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // after screen rotation, the following code is no meaningful and leak memory here
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    //
    OnDateUpdateListener iOnDateUpdateListener = (OnDateUpdateListener)getTargetFragment();
    if(iOnDateUpdateListener != null){
        iOnDateUpdateListener.onDateUpdate(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

}

I added source code to prevent DialogFragment is created again when configuration change, see the following code:

```
        mBtnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isDialogShow() == true){
                return;
            }

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment iDatePickerFragment = (DatePickerFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_DATEPICKER); 
            if(iDatePickerFragment ==null){
                iDatePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                iDatePickerFragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentInput.this,0);
                //add to FragmentManager
                iDatePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), TAG_DATEPICKER);
            }   

        }
    });
```

**step 1:** show this dialog => onCreateDialog is called

**step 2:** change date in DatePicker

**step 3:** rotate screen => onCreateDialog is recalled again. but date change in step 2 is kept and date in onCreateDialog is not updated. The source code in this step is no meaningful and and memory is allocate here.

**my questions:**

1. please help me explain that
2. if I want to reset date to current date or set date to other than "step2", what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When a config change occurs the old Fragment isn't destroyed -- it adds itself back to the Activity when it's recreated

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // only create fragment if activity is started for the first time
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
} else {        
    // do nothing - fragment is recreated automatically
}
```

Comment: I don't check savedInstanceState == null. I use another way, please see my source code I have just updated. in case we have 2 dialog TimepickerDialog and DatepikerDialog, your source code make memory bigger even though we don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after call onCreateDialog(), Date is changed to the value before Screen Rotation.
I tried to add source code update date in onResume() function, it is ok:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    mDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(year, month, day);
}
```